# Django signals is functioning even for django - admin when written for a model

Tags: python, django, model, signals

```
class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)

def create_form(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('form sent')

post_save.connect(receiver = create_form, sender= Leave)
```

I've written a `post_save` signal for my model, so that each time the `ModelForm` is saved it print's `form sent`, but the same happens if I alter some fields in the `/admin` and `save`. How do I stop that and write another `signal` if admin alters any field.

I've tried this for admin but it doesn't work

```
from django.contrib import admin
def admin_alter(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if Leave.status == '1':
        print('admin altered')

post_save.connect(receiver = after_accepting, sender= admin)
```

Comment: If you only want this to be triggered sometimes, why make it a signal at all? Why not do this in the view that processes the form, or even in the form itself?

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160284/how-to-use-signals-in-django-to-save-data-into-models?noredirect=1#comment91270230_52160284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: signals are for inter-applications communications. The point is to allow an application B to get informed of things happening in application A without having to modify A in anyway. Here your are working within the same application so [using signals here is an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/).

Second point: the `models.post_save` is sent whenever a model instance's `save()` method is called, wherever it is called from - your own form, the model admin, a managament command, and even from within an interactive shell, so you cannot have distinct signal handlers depending on where the model's `save()` has been called.

Now the solution is quite simple: don't use signals, just override the different methods calling your model's save (your form's `save()` method, your admin's form `save()` method etc etc) and add whatever code you want at those points.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160284/how-to-use-signals-in-django-to-save-data-into-models?noredirect=1#comment91270230_52160284